# firefox as addon installed run code

Tags: javascript, firefox

When a user adds our addon to their browser (firefox) as the browser restarts we would like it to run the function whats_new()

Where do we put the code for that?

Or in other words, is there some way I can run whats_new() as my plugin is loaded in Firefox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/Receiving_startup_notifications

**Longer Answer (with history):**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications

That URL describes the "app-startup" which I think is exactly what you want ... and it's no longer supported :-(

However, as this URL explains:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#Category_registration

there is now an alternate way of doing something similar, using the "profile-after-change" category.